# Ember animate view changes

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I experience an issue with animating the change of a particular view. I have two views which use among other properties the same 'options' parameter.
The DrawVisualizationView actually draws a chart with the options, that are obtained from inputs from the OptionsView.

The .hbs file:

```
<!-- Options Part --!>
<div> 
    {{view App.OptionsView options=controller.options}}
</div>
<!-- Visualization Part --!>
<div id="visualization">
    {{view App.DrawVisualizationView options=controller.options}}
</div>
```

I use [ember-animate](https://github.com/gigafied/ember-animate) to produce some animations between routes and I would like to produce an animation when I change the options and the chart is redrawn. For example, the old one would fade out and the new new would fade in. 
Both views use `VisualizationController` and `VisualizationRoute`, so I don't have any transitions between routes and controllers.

Here is DrawVisualizationView

```js
 App.DrawVisualizationView = Ember.View.extend({
        willAnimateIn: function() { //ember-animate method 
             //preparation
        },
        
        animateIn: function(done) {
          //some animation
        },
   
        animateOut: function(done) {
          //some animation
        },
   
         drawVisualization: function(){
           //draw a chart
         }.observes('options.@each').on('didInsertElement')
        
    });
```

The `VisualizationController` is set up in a way, that every change in `options` in `OptionsView` triggers redrawing of a chart through `DrawVisualizationView`.

`willAnimateIn`, `animateIn` and `animateOut` work only once during the loading of a page.

I tried events like `didInsertElement` and adding `eventManager` but none of them are triggered when the `DrawVisualizationView` is invoked after options changes.

Is there a way to trigger animate actions of the `DrawVisualizationView` if a particular option is changed?

Answer (score 0):

Author of `ember-animate`. If you want your view to re-animate when `options` changes, do this:

```
App.DrawVisualizationView = Ember.View.extend({

    willAnimateIn: function() { //ember-animate method 
        //preparation
    },

    animateIn: function(done) {
        //some animation
    },

    animateOut: function(done) {
        //some animation
    },

    drawVisualization: function () {

        this.animateOut(function () {
            this.willAnimateIn();
            this.animateIn();
        }.bind(this));

    }.observes('options.@each')

});
```